# How to use nested curly braces

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss

This works

```
#notifications .notice {
    @apply bg-purple-100;
}
#notifications .alert {
    @apply bg-pink-200;
}
```

But this doesn't work

```
#notifications {
    .notice {
        @apply bg-purple-100;
    }
    .alert {
        @apply bg-pink-200;
    }
}
```

Is it not possible to have nested curly braces in CSS?

Comment: It is not possible to have nested rules in CSS.

Comment: No just in SCSS/SASS.

Comment: Also I hate to be that guy, but that is literally a 10 seconds Google search. And you are not even a new user.

Comment: I'm no expert in Tailwind, but maybe "[Using with Preprocessors](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors)" is relevant.

Comment: Thanks @showdev. Seems like using SCSS files with Tailwind requires more steps and may not be worth it with Tailwind. I'll keep it simple and use CSS and not worry about nesting.

Comment: @vince hey, check this out https://github.com/dgknca/tailwind-postcss-html-starter you can use nested selectors with only postcss. no sass needed.  just enable it in `postcss.config.js` file.

Comment: thanks @doğukan this is perfect